# ImportError: No module named skimage, already have scikit-image installed

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to use skimage on mac, and already install the packages with virtualenv, but when I do "from skimage import io", it gave me this error :"ImportError: No module named skimage".
I am wondering if there is anything wrong installation process, but so far I cannot figure it out.

### Below is my installation process:

1. sudo pip install virtualenv
2. cd /my/project/folder
3. virtualenv myproject
4. source myproject/bin/activate
5. pip install -U scikit-image
   Then the result is:

   ### "Successfully installed PyWavelets-0.5.2 cycler-0.10.0 decorator-4.0.11 functools32-3.2.3.post2 matplotlib-2.0.0 networkx-1.11 numpy-1.12.1 olefile-0.44 pillow-4.0.0 python-dateutil-2.6.0 pytz-2017.2 scikit-image-0.13.0 scipy-0.19.0 subprocess32-3.2.7"

It seems that I already have everything, but why import skimage still failed?

Besides, I also tried to used the installation guidance on http://scikit-image.org/download with "pip install -U scikit-image" and "easy_install -U scikit-image", but also failed.

I am on Mac Sierra, with python 2.7. Any suggestion would highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue? I have the same problem and couldn't find a solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

conda environment manager fixes this problem.

```html
conda install --yes -c conda-forge scikit-image
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux and I couldn't get it working without doing

```
sudo apt-get install python-skimage
```

And I got that from the installation page of the docs:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/install.html

I'm not familiar with osx, but maybe try using a package manager like homebrew to install the package like so.

```
sudo homebrew install python-skimage
```

I'm actually quite puzzled as to why theres no OSX section in the install section of the docs, but a tiny bit of information in the downloads section.